# Bucheim-Walker corollary for DCGs

Tags: trees, dag

The Bucheim-Walker algorithm is used for drawing trees. However, there are many real-world examples where Directed Cyclic Graphs would benefit from such an algorithm (e.g. family trees with intermarriage or incestual relationships, dependency graphs, etc.). Can the algorithm be modified to support DCGs? If so, how?

Specifically, the Buchheim Walker algorithm does not support nodes with more than one ancestor, and more than one root node (and by extension, graph cycles). Is there another algorithm that can be used to achieve identical results?

By identical, I mean that the graph exhibits the following properties:

1. Symmetry: The algorithm attempts to draw trees in a symmetric fashion. Siblings are placed next to each other, and subtrees of a node are drawn symmetrically around the vertical axis of the node.
2. Compactness: The algorithm aims to minimize the amount of space it occupies. It tries to place nodes as close to each other as possible without overlapping, making efficient use of the available space.
3. Uniformity: Nodes at the same level (depth) in the tree are drawn on the same horizontal line (in the case of a vertical layout) or vertical line (in the case of a horizontal layout), giving a clean, organized appearance.
4. Clear Edges: Edges between parent and child nodes are drawn clearly, typically as straight lines. This makes the hierarchy and relationships within the tree easy to follow.
5. Balanced Layout: The layout of the nodes is balanced around their parent nodes. This means that the algorithm doesn't just place child nodes randomly or linearly but considers the placement of each node to create a visually balanced tree.
6. Minimized Edge Crossings: The algorithm attempts to reduce the number of crossings between edges connecting nodes. This makes the tree easier to read and understand, as it reduces visual clutter and confusion.

I have not been able to find anything, and have been breaking my teeth on this for months.

I am imagining something like [this](https://giphy.com/gifs/tree-flutter-graphview-jQ7fdMc5HmyQRoikaK).

Comment: That's a good start, but I'm still a bit confused about some of the details.  What do you mean by "identical results"?  I am not sure what you are asking for.  Are you asking for an algorithm to visualize graphs?  If so, is any algorithm OK, or do you want the visualizations to have a specific property?  Are there some requirements on the particular visualization that is produced?  Bucheim-Walker is just a means to accomplish something, but what is the something you want to accomplish?  "Tidy" sounds subjective; can you make that more precise?

Comment: @D.W. thank you for patiently proofreading and suggesting edits. Is the new version clear?